# Are there any formal algorithms for generating off mesh links between navmesh chunks for NPC characters?

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development, navmesh

I’m investigating different approaches for generating off mesh links between pieces of navmesh that allow NPC character to move around the game world. Are there any formal algorithms for generating these links? For example, is there any information on what algorithms Unity uses for their off mesh links or what Unreal uses for their nav links when automatically generating them using the navmesh?

I would like to implement my own system in my own game engine to generate jumps for characters using their navmesh and I am looking for inspiration.